# How to boot .iso image?

Tags: boot, iso-image

**Currently:**

I have an iso image which I downloaded. I have tested it on a virtual machine and it **works**.

Now I want to install it on my actual PC, however although I can burn it on a USB, I don't want to use it.

I have heard and used EasyBCD however I am currently having some problems opening it and running it.

**My Question:**

Is there an alternate to EasyBCD that allows you to boot from a bootable iso image? If so, what is it called?

*Note: I am currently running a dual boot with Ubuntu, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. My grub boot loader is in tact, and so is my Windows 8.1/Windows 10 boot manager/loader.*

Comment: If you want help regarding EasyBCD, you should make it clear in your question. If you are asking for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), Super User is not the place to do it.

Comment: @MC10 I am asking how to boot an iso image. There maybe a manual method of doing so. I stated that I used EasyBCD so that if someone was to answer they would not include this in their answer.

Comment: While it’s certainly possible to use a RAM disk for this, most modern operating systems do not support this in their default configuration! They crash after early boot.

Comment: What medium do you want to boot from if not a USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [Easy2boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/introduction/), it can be installed along side documents on a USB key.

Be careful when you have copied your ISO on the USB.  Two pieces of advice:

1. the file is **contiguous**. If not you can have trouble booting your ISO. Once Easy2Boot is installed, you can run [Wincontig](http://wincontig.mdtzone.it/en/) shipped in the `_ISO/docs/WINCONTIG` folder.
2. the file is **not corrupted**. Check the [MD5sum](http://winmd5.com/) of your ISO and compare it with the information provided by the website where you downloaded the ISO. Sometimes, bad copying / defragmenting can corrupt the ISO.

Comment: Quote: "However although I can burn it on a USB, I don't want to use it."

Comment: For my opinion, burning an ISO on a USB drive is not the same as copying the ISO file on a USB drive. When you burn it, you loose all your data on your USB, the solution provided allows you to keep your files on the USB drive.

Comment: That wasn't what I thought he meant - I understood him to mean he DOES NOT WANT TO USE USB. Read the quote above. I also added a link to a usb boot loader (in my answer) for iso mounting on fly in case he wanted it.. Maybe if he would clean up his question we could get somewhere.